# Invalid Pointer error while debugging web application in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I tried to run my web application using F5 key. I am getting invalid pointer error while debugging application.

Also getting below error in "ActivityLog.xml" file of visual studio.

```
CreateInstance failed for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceLogPackage.TraceLogPackage]Source: 'mscorlib' Description: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.HubExtensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceLogPackage.TraceLogPackage..ctor() 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) 
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) 
    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) 
    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName) 
    at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName)System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.HubExtensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.HubExtensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' 
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceLogPackage.TraceLogPackage..ctor() WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

I tried many solutions listed as below..

1. Clear temp files
2. Reset visual studio environment
3. Restart system
4. Repair Visual Studio 2015

But still I am not able to fix this issue. Please help me this fix this.

Comment: please add logs

Comment: added in question. Please check

Comment: @Dharmesh Parekh, Which VS2015 version did you use? Is it the latest VS 2015 version? Could you find this dll file in your windows like VS setup path: \Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies? Run VS as the admin, debug it. Or just run your VS in safe mode: Devenv.exe /safemode, debug your app again.

Comment: @Jack, I am using visual studio enterprise 2015 version. I also tried debugging in safe mode. But getting same error.

Comment: @Dharmesh Parekh, Could you debug this app in other VS2015 Environment? If you could find the dll file and it works well in other VS machine, maybe you could think about copying the dll file from other  Environment to yours, view the result. Please also take a backup for it in your current machine before you paste it. In addition, not debug your app, just run it using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", how about the result?